# scheduling a cron job to run a script that pings an IP address and save it to a log file

Tags: linux, shell, cron, zsh, ping

I wrote a shell script that ping once an IP address and echoes the results of the ping with the addition of the date command.
If I run the script by my self it works just fine and I can also save the script's results to a file with the >> operator like this:
script.sh >> log_file.
The problem starts when I scheduling it in the crontab editor then only the date command result is saved to a file without the ping result.

**my script is:**

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $(date +"%T %D")
ping -c1 google.com | while read replay
do
 echo $replay
done
```

**and the corn job is:**

```
* * * * * ~/new_scrip.sh >> /tmp/plog
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a ) on the second line.

Comment: my misspell :) - not missing in the scripts

Comment: Check if `ping` is in cron's PATH (which can be different than PATH in your interactive session). Alternatively call `which ping` and put absolute path for ping to your script.

Comment: is a typo in the code

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `-c1`, thus do only 1 ping anyway, you do not need the `while` part. So you could modify new_script.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $(date +"%T %D")
ping -c1 google.com
```

Then in crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/YOURUSER/new_scrip.sh >> /tmp/plog
```

Since cron runs under the `root` user, `~` expansion will not expand to your user, it will expand to root's home directory.  Therefore in crontab entries, you should put the complete path.

Another "trick" with crontab entries is to capture errors.

```
* * * * * /home/YOURUSER/new_scrip.sh >>/tmp/plog 2>>/tmp/errors
```

Any failure will be easy to pinpoint, if ever.